# regex to extract html comment attribute

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a table cell with the following comment:

```
 <!-- FieldName="Predicted Process Equipment Potable Usage"
             FieldInternalName="PredictedProcessEquipmentPotable"
             FieldType="SPFieldNumber" -->
```

There are many table cells with similar pattern comments, where the values of the attribute differ, but the attributes are always the same (FieldName, FieldInternalName, and FieldType).

How do I extract using REGEX the FieldInternalname in this type of comment?
Is there a non-regex way of doing it too?

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below regex and get the value of `FieldInternalName` from group index 1.

```
<!--[\S\s]*?FieldInternalName="([^"]*)"[\S\s]*?-->
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cQ2cF4/9)

```
> var m = 'foo\n <!-- FieldName="Predicted Process Equipment Potable Usage"\n            FieldInternalName="PredictedProcessEquipmentPotable"\n           FieldType="SPFieldNumber" -->';
undefined
> console.log(/<!--[\S\s]*?FieldInternalName="([^"]*)"[\S\s]*?-->/.exec(m)[1]);
PredictedProcessEquipmentPotable
```

Comment: This seems to work, but how do I run this regex in Javascript on the above comment to extract the value of FieldInternalName?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a non-regex way of doing it too?

```
commentNode.data;
```

*Comment* nodes have *nodeType* of `8`, so if you don't know which child of the cell it will be, you can write a function like this

```
function getNodesByType(node, type, childrenOnly) {
    var i,
        o = [];
    if (node.childNodes && node.childNodes.length)
        for (i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i)
            if (node.childNodes[i].nodeType === type)
                o.push(node.childNodes[i]);
            else if (!childrenOnly && node.childNodes[i].nodeType === 1)
                Array.prototype.push.apply(
                    o,
                    getNodesByType(node.childNodes[i], type, childrenOnly)
                );
    return o;
}
```

And invoke `getNodesByType(yourTdElement, 8, true);` to get an *Array* of comment nodes which are immediate children of your `<td>`